# Unit Test ASP.net Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, unit-testing

How can create a unit test for the the Page_Load function in ASP.net?

I am using build in Visual Studio Unit test frame work. I want to create a unit test that check the Elements of the web page and their values.

I know about selenium and its abilities in unit testing.

This is the web Page to test WebPageControl.ascx.vb:

```
   Public Class WebPageControl
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            TextBox.Visible = False
        End Sub
End Class
```

This is the Unit test WebPageControlTest.vb:

```
Public Class WebPageControlTest
    Public Sub PageLoadTest()

        Dim target As WebPageControl_Accessor = New WebPageControl_Accessor() 
        Assert.IsFAlse(target.TextBox.Visible)
    End Sub
End Class
```

After I do this I still get an error

```
Test method RechargeTest.WebPageControlTest.PageLoadTest threw exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not going to be able to new up a Page outside of the ASP.NET runtime.

You may want to google around for the MVP (Model-View-Presenter) pattern under ASP.NET. It makes testing web code a lot easier IMHO. This article is a good starting point:

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/09/ASP.NETSupervisingControllerModelViewPresenterFromSchematicToUnitTestsToCode.aspx

Comment: there should be methods to run automated tests on classic ASP.net since it has been out for a decade now. iMacro is one but i don't know if it will text your situation. Maybe someone can respond with something better

Comment: @kacalapy You can use Selenium for that, as the OP stated. If you want to test without running the whole web application though, and write actual unit tests instead of integration tests, I would recommend checking out the MVP pattern. Since the Presenters are responsible for doing most of the work and they are split out from ASP.NET, it's very easy to write test code for those Presenters. It's similar pattern to MVC, and speaking from experience I feel that it works quite well.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I have a question now is it uncommon to test web forms?

Comment: I would say it's uncommon to test web forms directly using a tool like NUnit or the VS.NET Unit Test framework. For testing web forms, a tool like Selenium would probably work well (although I haven't used it). The way I understand it is you basically need to make HTTP requests and check the results. These tests are really integration tests, because they depend on the whole application working properly. It's going to be hard with that approach though to test situations like: a user enters valid data into a form and clicks ok but then a db error occurs, is the right error message displayed?

Comment: If you use a pattern like MVP, you have a new class called a Presenter that is isolated from ASP.NET. I can't go into all of the details here, but using MVP makes testing the situation I mentioned above very easy because you can mock/stub out your web form (which is the View) and your Model (your data classes, which is especially easy if you are using IoC) and then you just make sure the Presenter flips the appropriate switches on the View to display the error message.

Answer (score 3):

If you want testable ASP.NET WebForms code, check out this project.
http://webformsmvp.com/

Comment: This link is broken. It is at [github.com/webformsmvp/webformsmvp](https://github.com/webformsmvp/webformsmvp) now.

Answer (score 2):

Web forms really wasn't built to be run through unit testing.  [Here's](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/testing-aspnet-webforms) a good article on what I'm talking about.  If you really want your pages to be testable I'd consider moving over to asp.net mvc or mvp.