# Unit Test Page_Load Calls another Method using Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, webforms

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                                           
    this.LoadImportantActionsToPage();               
}
```

All I want to do is write a unit test that tests that `LoadImportantActionsToPage`, which is private is called from `Page_Load`. I have no liberty to use MVC or MVP but I need to test it somehow.

Perhaps mocking th page?

Can it be done and could someone please give me an example as I can't find any on the web.

Comment: what a kind of question is this? if you have the code above can't you simply debug and step into the private method and check if it gets called. Of course once you are inside any method of a class, you can call private methods as well, this is basic OOP

Comment: @Davide - Sorry, I meant writing a unit test and have amended the question.

Comment: ok, so you can have a unit test which calls public methods of the page, in your case the Page_Load is protected, have a look at this question/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715654/unit-test-protected-method-in-c-sharp-using-moq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test ASP.net Page\_Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624874/unit-test-asp-net-page-load)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've got no chance with WebForms, as far as I'm concerned, particularly when it comes to mocking things like the HttpContext and 'web' stuff. With MVC you *do* have the capability to do this, with a little prior knowledge and understanding.

Switch to MVC3, adopt Ninject, StructureMap or Castle for IoC and constructor DI and use a mocking framework like Rhino Mocks or Moq, then you'll be able to write testable code and create worthwhile tests.

A quick google revealed a working example: http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/24/dependency-injection-with-ninject-moq-and-unit-testing/

Good luck

Comment: Thanks SapceBison - but I know how to test well in MVC3 - as the question says I must use webforms - I have bo control over this!

Comment: Rather you than me then, is all I can say to that ;)