# Can We write Unit test methods in .aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

Can we write test methods in .aspx.cs page?
If yes then how?
I need to write test method for the code which is in Page_Load method.
Please suggest if there is any solution.

Comment: What exactly do you need to test? UI code or business logic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test ASP.net Page\_Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624874/unit-test-asp-net-page-load)

Answer (score 5):

Probably you can, but it will be much cleaner if you extract the logic of the `Page_Load` method into a model class and then test it separately.

#### Why?

- Reuse logic of the method in other pages
- Better separation of model and presentation
- Cleaner code that is easier to test

Sample:

```
// Home.aspx.cs
Page_Load()
{
    //Lots of code here
}


// or else Home.aspx.cs
Page_Load()
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    var result = f.DoThings();
}

//Unit test
Page_Load_FooDoesThings()
{
    //Arrange
    Foo f = new Foo();
    var expected = ...;
    
    //Act
    var actual = f.DoThings();
    
    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
}
```

Comment: But what if you want to test that your page_load makes specific calls into your shared business logic classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a test method anywhere, You just need to use 3A rule (Arrange, Act, Assert) and decorate your methods based on which testing framework you are using. You can test almost anything using a testing framework, properties, methods etc.

However, the best practice is to create a separate project for tests.

Also `Page_Load` like other page lifecycle methods isn't a good option for testing because it'll be cumbersome to get it testable. I agree with "oleksii" that functionality is something we can test outside `Page_Load` method.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can. If you add some testing method in your `Page_Load`, it is programmaticly ok. But **you shouldn't**. Because if you can define your testing methods in your `Page_Load`, your test will run unnecessary every page loading. This is not a following method in unit testing. That's could why `Visual Studio` creates a seperate testing project.